# (very long string)modulo to int cpp

Tags: c++, modulo

How to convert a (very long string) modulo say `string="45345543534545623243464534545645"` to `int`. I tried `stoi(string)%someno` . But compiler is showing "out of range" error.

Comment: What do you want the result of this conversion to be ?

Comment: You cannot take a module from a string, and you can't make C++ do it itself, because it cannot operate with such big numbers. It looks like you need to use [bignum arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) - either 3rd party classes or write it yourself.

Comment: please read about integers and strings first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process the string yourself, digit by digit. Say the modulo is m.

Start with `int firstDigit = firstLetter-'0';` Set `x` to `firstDigit % m`.

While there are digits left, repeat `nextDigit = nextLetter-'0'`;
and calculate `x = (x*10 + nextDigit)% m`.

Comment: can i use stoi(string[i]) instead of firstletter - '0'